# PyODBC SQL code stuck in Python, but run smoothly in separate function

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I am using Python 2.7 64-Bit on Windows 7 and pyodbc. Database wise, it is Microsoft SQL Server 2008R2.

I am trying to execute a piece of SQL code below:

```
DECLARE 
     @Min INT
,    @Max INT

SELECT
     @Min = 50
,    @Max = 50000                      
update staging.tmp_python
     set Flag =  case 
                    when Value between @Min  and @Max  then 1
                    else 0
                 end
```

The SQL code run smoothly in SQL, it takes around 3 seconds. But when I try to run it in Python as following, it takes ages and I don't think it is really doing anything.

```
SQL_command = """
                  DECLARE 
                       @Min INT
                  ,    @Max INT

                  SELECT
                       @Min = 50
                  ,    @Max = 50000                       
                  update staging.tmp_python
                       set Flag =  case 
                                      when Value between @Min  and @Max  
                                      then 1
                                      else 0
                                   end
             """
conn = pyodbc.connect("driver={SQL Server};server= MyServer;database=MyDatabase;trusted_connection=true") 

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute(SQL_command)
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried something simpler? Like: `conn = pyodbc.connect("driver={SQL Server};server= MyServer;database=MyDatabase;trusted_connection=true")` then: `cursor=conn.cursor()` then: `cursor.execute('SELECT 1')` from the Python command line?

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code into a Python 2.7.5 script and it worked fine for me. As for it not "really doing anything", did you remember to `conn.commit()` ...?

Comment: @FlipperPA Yes, I've tried. The above code is a part of a program, it runs well before this.